# Modify a \part entry in ToC with memoir

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir

I would like to change how a "Part" title appears in the Table of Contents of a `memoir` document. In particular, I'd like to have the "Part Title" between two lines. Take the following minimal example:

```
\documentclass[b5paper,10pt,twoside,openright,final,english]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\makepagestyle{part}
\makeevenfoot{part}{}{}{}
\makeoddfoot{part}{}{}{}
\makeevenhead{part}{}{}{}
\makeoddhead{part}{}{}{}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum

\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\mbox{}\protect\hrulefill\par}
\part{Basics}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\mbox{}\protect\hrulefill\par}

\chapter{A Chapter}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

How can I force the lines in the Table of Contents to be longer and change the distance within the "Part" title?

Answer (score 3):

This way you can change the distance before the part entry:

```
\setlength{\cftbeforepartskip}{1ex}
```

And to fill to whole line, make a skip to the left:

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\hskip -\memRTLleftskip\protect\mbox{}\protect\hrulefill\par}
```

Here's a definition which does it once for all parts:

```
\setlength{\cftbeforepartskip}{0pt}
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro{\cftpartbreak}{\hskip -\parindent\hrulefill\par}
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\cftpartafterpnum}{\par\vspace{-1.5ex}\hskip -\memRTLleftskip\hrulefill}
```

[image: parts entries with lines]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now I got how to change the length, however the second command does not seem to work. In fact, I would like the horizontal lines to start at same place where "I" appears in the ToC, whereas they start at "Basics"

Comment: @Daniele I updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Working from Stefan's answer, if you want lines before and after the part title, the following would work:

```
\renewcommand{\cftpartafterpnum}{\par %
\vspace{-2\baselineskip} \hskip -\memRTLleftskip\protect\mbox{}\protect\hrulefill\par%
\vspace{0.5\baselineskip} \hskip -\memRTLleftskip\protect\mbox{}\protect\hrulefill\par}
```

[image]

See section 9.2 of [memman.pdf](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/memman.pdf) for more information about `\cftpartafterpnum` and related commands.

Comment: I just found that if I also use the `\cftpagenumbersoff{part}` command (so that the page number where the part starts does not appear in the ToC) the two lines will be shorter! Is it possible to let them go until the end of the line, even when `\cftpagenumbersoff{part}` is used?