# Clash between the "linktocpage" option of the hyperref package and the "\cftchapterpagefont" command of memoir class

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, memoir

I'm trying to produce a document using the memoir class and the `hyperref` package. Unfortunately, I get a lot of errors when I try to use  the `linktocpage` option of the `hyperref` package with `\renewcommand{\cftchapterpagefont}{\textrm}`.

I guess the solution will be on the lines of [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/219141/131303) to a similar problem, but I haven't been able to figure it out. Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[openany,oneside,11pt]{memoir}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Turkish character and language support
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[turkish,shorthands=:!]{babel}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Required packages
\RequirePackage{amssymb,amsmath,hyperref,multicol,ifthen,graphicx,pifont,rotating,xcolor}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% The  TOC
\cftsetindents{part}{0em}{3.0em}% Indendation and numwidth for part titles in the TOC
\cftsetindents{chapter}{1em}{2.0em}% Indendation and numwidth for chapter titles in the TOC
\setlength{\cftbeforechapterskip}{0pt}% No gap between chapter titles in the TOC
\renewcommand{\cftchapterfont}{\textrm}% Chapter title font in the TOC
\renewcommand{\cftchapterpagefont}{\textrm}% Clashes with the "linktocpage" option of the hyperref package
\renewcommand{\cftpartafterpnum}{\par % Thanks to https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/42500
    \vspace{-2\baselineskip} \hskip -\memRTLleftskip\protect\mbox{}\protect\hrulefill\par%
    \vspace{0.5\baselineskip} \hskip -\memRTLleftskip\protect\mbox{}\protect\hrulefill\par}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% hyperref setup
\hypersetup{%
    unicode={true}, % 
    bookmarks={true}, %
    colorlinks={true}, %
    allcolors={kmavi},%
    linktocpage={true}, % In TOC, links and colors for page numbers only.
    pdfdisplaydoctitle={true}
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% The colors
\definecolor{kmavi}{RGB}{0,80,117}
\definecolor{mavi}{RGB}{0,115,168}

\begin{document}

\currentpdfbookmark{Table of Contents}{name}
\tableofcontents*

\part{My First Part}
\chapter{My First Chapter}
\chapter{My Second Chapter}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. `\renewcommand{\cftchapterpagefont}{\textrm}` does not look really healthy there. Try `\renewcommand{\cftchapterpagefont}{\rmfamily}` instead

Comment: I can't believe it, your suggestion is so simple and it works perfectly. Thank you very much!

Comment: Also load `hyperref` at the end of the preamble almost always, not somewhere in between.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `hyperref` uses the `page` number as link anchor, `\renewcommand{cftchapterpagefont}{\textrm}` will fail due to that fact that is expecting an argument.

Use

```
\renewcommand{\cftchapterpagefont}{\rmfamily}
```

instead, which is a font switch not needing an argument.

```
\documentclass[openany,oneside,11pt]{memoir}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Turkish character and language support
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[turkish,shorthands=:!]{babel}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Required packages
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{xcolor}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% The  TOC
\cftsetindents{part}{0em}{3.0em}% Indendation and numwidth for part titles in the TOC
\cftsetindents{chapter}{1em}{2.0em}% Indendation and numwidth for chapter titles in the TOC
\setlength{\cftbeforechapterskip}{0pt}% No gap between chapter titles in the TOC
\renewcommand{\cftchapterfont}{\rmfamily}% Chapter title font in the TOC
\renewcommand{\cftchapterpagefont}{\rmfamily}% Clashes with the "linktocpage" option of the hyperref package
\renewcommand{\cftpartafterpnum}{\par % Thanks to https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/42500
    \vspace{-2\baselineskip} \hskip -\memRTLleftskip\protect\mbox{}\protect\hrulefill\par%
    \vspace{0.5\baselineskip} \hskip -\memRTLleftskip\protect\mbox{}\protect\hrulefill\par}

\usepackage{hyperref}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% hyperref setup
\hypersetup{%
    unicode={true}, % 
    bookmarks={true}, %
    colorlinks={true}, %
    allcolors={kmavi},%
    linktocpage={true}, % In TOC, links and colors for page numbers only.
    pdfdisplaydoctitle={true}
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% The colors
\definecolor{kmavi}{RGB}{0,80,117}
\definecolor{mavi}{RGB}{0,115,168}

\begin{document}

\currentpdfbookmark{Table of Contents}{name}
\tableofcontents*

\part{My First Part}
\chapter{My First Chapter}
\chapter{My Second Chapter}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much again for your clear explanation and perfect solution.